# connect mysql with ruby without rails gives error in ruby version 2

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have included given code in my db.rb file

```
require "mysql2"    # if needed

@db_host  = "localhost"
@db_user  = "root"
@db_pass  = "root"
@db_name = "farji"

client = Mysql::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
@cdr_result = client.query("SELECT * from employee')
```

and in terminal i have install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev
gem install mysql2
```

and run ruby db.rb it gives me error db.rb:8:in `': uninitialized constant Mysql (NameError)
my ruby version is ruby-2.1.5
Please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: The gem you installed and `require`d is `mysql2`. The module is `Mysql2` so you need to be instantiating a `Mysql2::Client`.

Comment: Thankyou it works :)